# AOP? Adapters? Reflections? How do I generify setter methods (without abstracting the target object)

Tags: java

I would like to create a generic setter for any objects that can take setBar or setFoo. These are located within a library so I will not be able to adjust the source for any of these classes to inherit from a parent type.

Constraints: I am using a third party library which will not make it possible for me to give these Objects a parent class to extend off of.

e.g.:

```
class Object1 {
    void setBar(String str){...}
    void setFoo(String str){...}
}

class Object2 {
    void setBar(String str){...}
    void setFoo(String str){...}
}

class Object3 {
    void setBar(String str){...}
    void setFoo(String str){...}
}
```

I am trying to determine the following:

Is there any way to create an Adapter design pattern using AOP or Reflections to work around the constraint and limit the amount of code needed to handle the setters for each object?

What steps can I take so that I can create a single method which will cover the setters for any of these Objects (if called upon)

Comment: I'm confused. What is your real goal? Do you want a method that accepts three arguments, one for each setter? What do you mean by _single method_? Are you really trying to invoke the setters on objects you're throwing away immediately?

Comment: Can you give an example how your single method would be invoked and what it would do? For example do you want to call setSetter2(..) on any object that is of either class object1, object2, or object 3? Of if not that, what should it do?

Comment: Adjusted my question. The goal is to make a common setBar and setFoo. Keep in mind that I can't give it an interface to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), that implement a common interface:

```
interface CommonInterface {
    void setBar(String str);
    void setFoo(String str);
}

class Object1Adapter implements CommonInterface {
    private final Object1 obj;

    public Object1Adapter(Object1 obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBar(String str) {
        obj.setBar(str);
    }
    ...
}

class Object2Adapter implements CommonInterface {...}
class Object3Adapter implements CommonInterface {...}
```

Then you can then store the adapters under the `CommonInterface` type.

---

If you want to call the setters in `CommonInterface` using 1 funnelling method you could do this (you will still need the adapter classes):

```
interface CommonInterface {
    enum Setter {
        Bar,
        Foo;
    }

    void setBar(String str);
    void setFoo(String str);

    default void set(Setter set, String value) {
        switch(set) {
        case Bar:
            setBar(value);
            break;
        case Foo:
            setFoo(value);
            break;
        default: // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it all like this:

```
CommonInterface obj = new Object1Adapter(new Object1());
obj.set(CommonInterface.Setter.Bar, "Hello"); // Uses 'setBar'
```